# how this loop can work if the input (src) is a Mat image?

Tags: opencv

I am working on some averaging of pixels and I know this loop can work with any 2d array. But how can this work if the src is a Mat image (OpenCV)?
I have so much difficulty pass these parameters in the function for a Mat image
Does my question make sense?

```
#include <iostream>

const unsigned dim = 3;
typedef int array_type [dim][dim];
```

Here is the loop:

```
void average(array_type& dest, const array_type& src)
{
    // corners:
    dest[  0  ][  0  ] = 
        (src[  0  ][  0  ] + src[  0  ][  1  ] + src[  1  ][  0  ] + src[  1  ][  1  ])/4;
    dest[dim-1][  0  ] = 
        (src[dim-1][  0  ] + src[dim-2][  0  ] + src[dim-1][  1  ] + src[dim-2][  1  ])/4;
    dest[  0  ][dim-1] = 
        (src[  0  ][dim-1] + src[  1  ][dim-1] + src[  0  ][dim-2] + src[  1  ][dim-2])/4;
    dest[dim-1][dim-1] = 
        (src[dim-1][dim-1] + src[dim-2][dim-1] + src[dim-1][dim-2] + src[dim-2][dim-2])/4;

    // top, bottom, and sides:
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < dim - 1; ++i)
    {
        const unsigned j = dim - 1;

        dest[0][i] = 
            (src[0][i-1] + src[0][i] + src[0][i+1] + src[ 1 ][i-1] + src[ 1 ][i] + src[ 1 ][i+1])/6;
        dest[j][i] = 
            (src[j][i-1] + src[j][i] + src[j][i+1] + src[j-1][i-1] + src[j-1][i] + src[j-1][i+1])/6;

        dest[i][0] = 
            (src[i-1][0] + src[i][0] + src[i+1][0] + src[i-1][ 1 ] + src[i][ 1 ] + src[i+1][ 1 ])/6;
        dest[i][j] = 
            (src[i-1][j] + src[i][j] + src[i+1][j] + src[i-1][j-1] + src[i][j-1] + src[i+1][j-1])/6;
    }

    // middle:
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < dim - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 1; j < dim - 1; ++j)
        {
            dest[i][j] = (src[i-1][j-1] + src[i-1][j] + src[i-1][j+1] +
                          src[ i ][j-1] + src[ i ][j] + src[ i ][j+1] +
                          src[i+1][j-1] + src[i+1][j] + src[i+1][j+1]) / 9 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just want to know how to access the `Mat image` pixels as you do in a 2D array. See the code below:

```
for(int i=0; i<image.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<image.cols; j++)
    {
        value_from_Mat_array = image.at<uchar>(i,j);
    }
}
```

So, `i,j` are the indices similar to which you have in 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

you probably would not loop at all with opencv, but use [filter2D()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) instead:

```
Mat img; // your original image
Mat res; // filtered
Mat kernel(3,3,CV_32F,Scalar(1.0f/9));
filter2D(img,res,-1,kernel);
```